# Books/resources for the study of non-flat spacetime shadows

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, resource-recommendations, shadow

I'm preparing a research paper (and possible review) on shadow calculation in asymptotically non-flat spacetime. I have been searching the internet for some references and the only thing I found was this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07101) (page 24) with a comment on the subject.

Could someone guide me or refer me to a source that contains what I'm looking for?

Comment: That paper also has a section on shadows in cosmological backgrounds, which are not asymptotically flat. In general, the method is the same but you have to be careful when calculating the angles seen by the observer.